# Call function BackHandler only on one page

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using the BackHandler function to close my application during the native Back button event of Android. I want this function to close the application to work only when it is on a specific page. How do I do this?

My Code:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
 BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPress);
}
componentDidMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPress);
}

 backPress = () => {
Alert.alert(
  'Exit app',
  'Exit app?',
  [
    { text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel' },
    { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
  ],
  { cancelable: false })
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a flag and update it accordingly whenever you generate each page to indicate if the dialog must be shown or not. Then edit your backPress function like this:

```
var app = {
    backButtonDialog: true
};

backPress = () => {
    if(app.backButtonDialog){
        // Prompt for exit
        Alert.alert(
          'Exit app',
          'Exit app?',
          [
            { text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel' },
            { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
          ],
          { cancelable: false })
        return true;
    }else{
        // Do nothing
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you simple set `app.backButtonDialog = true;` when you want the dialog to show up, and `app.backButtonDialog = false;` when you want the backbutton to do nothing.